# playPause is not defined (Not Play the Video)

Tags: javascript, html

In order to make video play when someone clicks on the play button, the button must become the pause icon to show that you can play and pause. Right now, the video does not play when I click on the play button. There is an error message that says playPause is not defined.

**ERROR**

```
1(index):131 Uncaught ReferenceError: playPause is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

**HTML** **JS**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var ppbutton = document.getElementById("vidbutton");
    ppbutton.addEventListener("click", playPause);
    myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");
    function playPause() {
        if (myVideo.paused) {
            myVideo.play();
            ppbutton.innerHTML = "Pause";
            }
        else  {
            myVideo.pause();
            ppbutton.innerHTML = "Play";
            }
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="video">
            <video height="369px" width="610px" muted id="video1" poster="assets/img/photo.jpg">
                <source src="/assets/video/bjp__video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="/assets/video/bjp__video.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video>

            <div class="name">
                <img alt="name" src="assets/img/bjp_title.png">
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="info__hero__content">
              <p>I help  <span><b>people with disabilities</b></span> and <span><b>entrepreneurs</b></span>  to find their hide abilities and resources for their businesses.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="play__btn">
      <button id="vidbutton" onclick="playPause()">
        <img alt="play button" src="/assets/img/play__button.svg">
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @BrandonPowell - this question is still open. If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below any answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, please choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside an answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer (to close the question). That would help us out. *Thanks!*

Comment: Hi @BrandonPowell - Did the below answer solve your question? If so, please mark it with the checkmark to close out the question. Otherwise, please update your question (or post a comment below the answer) to help us fine-tune our assistance. Or, please post your own answer to show how you solved the problem and checkmark that answer, again, to close out the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the onclick event from the button itself. That is what is causing the error.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var ppbutton = document.getElementById("vidbutton");
    ppbutton.addEventListener("click", playPause);
    myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");
    function playPause() {
        if (myVideo.paused) {
            myVideo.play();
            ppbutton.innerHTML = "Pause";
            }
        else  {
            myVideo.pause();
            ppbutton.innerHTML = "Play";
            }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="video">
            <video height="169px" width="410px" id="video1" poster="https://ourtube.co.uk/upload/photos/2021/11/928b8656defe100bf7c75815db0edf992b1e33d2wK9QTHR7ny9ahCHqPYKf.video_thumb_5245_11.jpeg">
                <source src="https://ourtube.co.uk/watch/TMaamxje77GKe9q" type="video/mp4">
            </video>

            <div class="name">
                <img alt="name" src="assets/img/bjp_title.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="info__hero__content">
              <p>I help  <span><b>people with disabilities</b></span> and <span><b>entrepreneurs</b></span>  to find their hide abilities and resources for their businesses.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="play__btn">
      <button id="vidbutton">
        <img alt="play button" src="https://brandnewtube.com/themes/youplay/img/icon.png"> Play
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working but to a point like a slow responce or don't work to a point and after the video stop working.

Comment: The slow/unstable video response is not related to this question (and it is probably not related to javascript). I suggest closing out this question (Checkmark a correct answer) and then ask a new question - you'll get hundreds of people reading the new question right away *(only a few will see comments added to this older question now)* and a much better chance for you to get a helpful answer.